# Serving htm or xml files from ApplicationHost

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I am hosting the ASP.Net runtime in my exe but I find that if I try to access htm or xml files from the browser, it gives a 404.

I can access aspx, asmx and other asp.net related files just fine.

Is there any configuration that I need to do to server other file extensions and if so, what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need:

```
<modules>
    <add name="DefaultDocumentModule" />
    <add name="DirectoryListingModule" />
    <add name="StaticFileModule" />
    <add name="AnonymousAuthenticationModule" />
</modules>
```

Check this walk-through for the complete configuration:
"[Walkthrough: Creating a Configuration File for Hosted Web Core (IIS 7)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms693807%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)"